# How much time it takes to verify a Bitcoin signature in the Satoshi client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, performance, signature, ecdsa

Assuming:

- An average modern computer
- Using a single thread, as the current Satoshi client does
- Using the OpenSSL library, as the Satoshi Bitcoin client does
- The signature is not in the signature cache

I speculate that the time may be between 1 and 10 msec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a lot on the hardware, and on the architecture. OpenSSL use some assembly-optimized routines, which result in a speed factor of +- x2 between 32 bit and 64 bit (the latter is faster). That said, I've seen verifications taking around 0.47 ms on an Intel Xeon E5-1650 @ 3.20GHz, using 64-bit code.

Also, version 0.8 will actually do signature verification in parallel. There is also a patch with an optimized ECDSA verifier for the specific curve we're using, which should give a 20% speedup (discovered by Hal Finney). This patch will probably not make it into v0.8, though.

Answer (score 4):

I instrumented the Satoshi client to see hwo long a transaction verification takes. This includes the signature verification, but is probably more of an upper bound as it also includes several disk seeks.

[image: Transaction verification time]

4500 Transactions. With the following percentiles:

- 50 percentile 5.0
- 75 percentile 10.0
- 85 percentile 15.0
- 95 percentile 36.0
- 99 percentile 207.27

While not at all representative it would point towards your estimate being correct.

Note: this was taken on a Lenovo T420 with spinning disks.

Comment: Just testing the digital signature verification using the OpenSSL code on a single core of a Core 2 Q9550, I get 725 microseconds per verification, a shade under 1 millisecond. This may be a bit unrealistic because all the ECDSA code is hot in the cache and the branch prediction is primed. (Test was doing verifications in a tight loop.)

Comment: The 0.8 code (unreleased currently) has a -benchmark function which measures block connection and signature verifications. You are certainly not just measuring signature validation.

Comment: Yep, I needed the benchmark for something else, where the whole processing time of transactions was more relevant.